# validates_uniqueness_of with a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I seem to encounter this problem from time to time when I want to validate a field and scope it to a particular date when I am storing datetime.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:starts_at, :state]
```

The problem is `starts_at` is stored as `datetime` but I don't want to validate the exact time but rather the general date.

When I encounter this problem I usually create a custom validation method, and sometimes that makes sense when there's a window of time, but I'm wondering if I'm overlooking a better solution when I only care about the entire date.

I would like to avoid creating custom validation like the one below if there's another possibility.

## Old way

```
def check_user_uniqueness
  if EventLog.where("start_at::date = ? AND id <> ? AND user_id = ?",
    start_at.to_date, id, user_id).count > 0
    errors.add(:user_id, "isn't available on this date")
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: I can only think of a **custom validation** for this. If `starts_at` is a **date(not datetime)** then it is achievable with `validates_uniqueness_of`.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite reasonable to create a custom validation for this, but you could just rather use `exists?` instead of `count`/`> 0` check, it is more readable and does exactly what u need:

```
def check_user_uniqueness
  if EventLog.where(id: id, user_id: user_id).exists?("start_at::date = ?", start_at.to_date)
    errors.add(:user_id, "isn't available on this date")
  end
end
```